# React importing images path from a constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import a constant into my component that has all the paths to the icons. But the images are broken i belief its the path but what ever path i try they just dont display

I have a component called Tile that that will be purley presentational and a TileContainer that imports the const with the logos paths, I will do some looping to pass the paths down with the prop to Tile.

Constant:
assets are in: src/assets/

```
in: src/components/tile/TileLogoConst.js
    `const icons = [
        {
          alt: 'React Logo HAHHA',
          source: '../../assets/react.png'  
        }
    ];

    export default icons;`
```

TileContainer:
in: src/components/Containers/tileContainer/TileContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tile from '../../tile/Tile';
import icons from '../../tile/TileLogoConst'

class TileContainer extends Component {

    getIcons (icon) {
        const troll = icon.map((i) => {
            return i.source;
        });
        return troll;
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>ITS ME</p>
                <img src={this.getIcons(icons)} alt="Trolololo" />
                {/* <Tile data={this.getIcons(icons)}/> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export { TileContainer };
```

i can see the the path is passed to img src in the DOM when i inspect element:

```
<img src="../../assets/react.png" alt="Trolololo">
```

But the image appears broken does the path to the images have to point to the correct path from the constant or from where to constant is imported..? either way i tried both. Even when i hard code the path to the img it still appears broken

Comment: Perhaps try "/assets/react.png" instead, so you don't have to worry about the relative path from any component.

Comment: Either @YannickK's solution above works or you can try `./../../assets/react.png` to have the relative path from the current dir.

Comment: if i understand correctly i should change my path in my Constant to `/assets/react.png`

Comment: I have directly imported one of the logos from assets:
 `import troll from '../../../assets/aws.png';` and added the var to image source:
`<img src={troll} alt="Trolololo" />` and that works, but when i import the TileLogoConst with updated src path to `../../../assets/aws.png';` it still does not work. I have put them side by side and noticed something strange in the dom:

`<img src="../../../assets/aws.png" alt="CONSTANT IMG">`
but the one that works looks like this:
`<img src="/static/media/aws.27e8e879.png" alt="Trolololo">`
why does the path looks different with random nums..?

Comment: Seems like this is something to do with create-react-app WebPack config